# Gradient of inner product in Hilbert space

Tags: derivatives, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and
\begin{align}
f&\colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}\\
f(x) &= ||x-c||_\mathcal{H} ^2
\end{align}
from some constant $c \in \mathbb{H}$

Is the derivative of $f$ at $x$ equal $2x-2c$?

I used 
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \langle x,x \rangle - 2\langle x,c \rangle + \langle c,c \rangle
\end{align}
and the standard rules for derivation

\begin{align}
\frac{\delta}{\delta x} f &= \frac{\delta}{\delta x} \langle x,x \rangle - \frac{\delta}{\delta x} 2\langle x,c \rangle + \frac{\delta}{\delta x} \langle c,c \rangle \\
&= 2x - 2 c
\end{align}

Are there any special "obstacles" I have to consider or can I just use the these rules as in the standard euclidean space?

Comment: if your Hilbert space is real, then everything is fine.

Comment: I would say that the derivative of $f$ is the linear map $Df(x) \colon h \mapsto 2\langle x-c\mid h \rangle$ and that $\nabla f(x) = 2(x-c)$. But you are right, up to Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: @Siminore may I ask you what do you mean by "up to Riesz representation theorem"?

Comment: Oh I think I found it on wikipedia. Thanks!