# How is Lipschitz continuity for Fréchet derivatives defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

Let $(X,||\cdot||_X)$ be a Banach space and $X^*$ it's dual of linear functionals $X\to\mathbb{R}$. The Fréchet derivative $\nabla f(x)$ of a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ at $x$ is an element of $X^*$.

What exactly does "Lipschitz-continuity of the gradient" mean in this context?

Is it $\forall x,y \in X$
$$
|| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)||_{X^*} \leq L || x -y ||_{X}
$$
where $|| g ||_{X^*} = \sup \{ |g(x)| : x \in X, ||x|| \leq 1 \}$ is the dual norm and $L$ the Lipschitz constant or

$$
|\langle \nabla f(z), x-y \rangle| \leq L || x -y ||_{X}
$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the duality map?

If the latter is correct, does it have to hold for all $z \in X$?

**Edit:** An example that would help me to understand this issue better would be
$$
f: x \mapsto  \frac{1}{2}||x-c||_X^2
$$
for some constant $c \in X$, with derivative $Df(x): h \mapsto \langle x-c,h \rangle$ and gradient $\nabla f(x) =  x-c$. How can I calculate the Lipschitz constant?

Comment: It is the first:  $
|| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)||_{X^*} \leq L || x -y ||_{X}
$

Comment: The second is always true - there the constant $L$ is just the dual norm of $\nabla f(z)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Fréchet derivative $\nabla f(x)$ of a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ at $x$ is an element of $X^*$.

And therefore, $\nabla f$ is a map from $X$ to $X^*$. The Lipschitz condition makes sense whenever there is a map between metric spaces; and both $X$ and $X^*$ have metrics  induced by their norms. Explicitly, 
$$\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|_{X^*} \leq L \| x -y \|_{X}$$

Your example 
$$f(x)  = \frac{1}{2}\|x-c\|_X^2$$
is very interesting. In a general Banach space, $\nabla f$ is not even defined: for example, the $\ell_1$ norm is not differentiable when one of coordinates is zero (consider  two-dimensional model to make this very explicit).

A space for which $f$ is Fréchet differentiable is called a space with Fréchet differentiable norm (the norm itself is of course not differentiable at $0$, but the term refers to differentiability at nonzero points). In [lecture 23 here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~schlump/lecture22and23.pdf) is is proved that in such a space, $\nabla f$ is automatically continuous. The map $\nabla f$ is called the support map or the duality map: it sends each element $x$ to a linear functional $\varphi $ such that $\|\varphi\|=\|x\|$ and $\|\varphi(x)\|=\|x\|^2$.

In general, $\nabla f$ is not even uniformly continuous, let alone Lipschitz continuous.

- $\nabla f$ is uniformly continuous $\iff$ $X$ is a uniformly smooth space
- $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz continuous $\iff$ $X$ is a uniformly smooth space with quadratic modulus of smoothness.

The Lipschitz constant of $\nabla f$ depends on the multiplicative constant in the modulus of smoothness.

Comment: Thx. Assume in the example `X` and `f` are sufficient "nice". I have a problem calculating $||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)||_{X^*}$ and think it should be $||Df(x) - Df(y)||$ or how do I evaluate $||x-c - y+c||_{X^*}$ for $\{z \in X, ||z|| \leq 1 \}$?

Comment: What does $Df$ mean, if not the same as $\nabla f$? How to find the Lipschitz constant of a map depends very much on what that map is. You mentioned the square of the norm... that is still too broad a question, it all depends on how the norm is defined. "How does one find the Lipschitz constant of some map?" by studying it in detail.

Comment: OK, then I got confused by the comment of @Siminore: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368470/gradient-of-inner-product-in-hilbert-space?noredirect=1#comment2785267_1368470

Comment: Ah, that was about Hilbert spaces. The geometry of the norm in Hilbert spaces is totally trivial compared to what one finds in Banach spaces.